# What is the term for the road shown in the photo?

Tags: word-request

Take a look at this photo:

[Valid XHTML http://img1.cfcdn.com/public/property-listing-images/full_size/51b80d4a3765e.gif](http://img1.cfcdn.com/public/property-listing-images/full_size/51b80d4a3765e.gif).

My question is what is the correct word to describe these roads (inside a residential colony) that lead to individual apartments, unlike the public roads? This is an image of the inside of a residential colony.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 'road' would usually refer exclusively to that which is driven on by motor vehicles.

What you've pictured is a 'path' which is [defined](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/path) as (in one of its senses):

> A trail for the use of, or worn by, pedestrians.

I don't believe there's a distinction in terms used between paths which are open to the public and those which are on private land.

Comment: See also: _[footpath](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+footpath),_ _[pavement](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+pavement),_ _[sidewalk](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sidewalk),_ _[walkway](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+walkway),_ _[pedway](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+pedway)._

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Great resources—*path* is perfectly acceptable and I'd understand it easily. But I'd be more likely to just call it a *sidewalk*.

Comment: @WendiKidd, to me OP's picture doesn't show a sidewalk because it's not alongside a road.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, that is what I said in the question description, it is not an actual road. It is like a huge area with a lot of apartments inside it.

Comment: _Sidewalk_ seems okay to me; after all, that walkway is alongside **something**. It might be worth noting [this definition](http://www.onelook.com/?w=sidewalk&ls=a) of _sidewalk_: walk consisting of a paved area for pedestrians; **usually** beside a street or roadway. Incidentally, if that walkway was beside a canal or other body of water, it could be called a [_riverwalk_](http://www.wordnik.com/words/riverwalk).

Comment: Note that "sidewalk" is an American English term; in British English it would be "pavement" - though as with the American equivalent, it would normally imply a path alongside a road.

Comment: Just to give a British English perspective: A 'pavement' is *exclusively* alongside a road. 'sidewalk' wouldn't be used, as it's an Am. English word, but it would be understood to mean the same. 'walkway' would usually refer to a passage between two buildings or certain types of bridge. 'pedway' wouldn't be used in Br. English. 'footpath' is the only one that would be considered potentially correct in this case. It would be most often used for a path in the countryside or a park, but is versatile. I wouldn't say it's *quite* the right word here, but I'm finding myself unable to explain why.

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: as other users have rightly said, the words' meanings can be different in American English, so may well be appropriate in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious word for that would be *path*. See [this dictionary definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/path_1?q=path).

Comment: I normally think of _paths_ as being [unpaved](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1510&bih=818&q=path&oq=path&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1576.1891.0.2195.4.4.0.0.0.0.137.347.2j2.4.0....0...1ac.1.25.img..1.3.209.JVth8w6sXvg) (although I readily acknowledge that paths _can_ be paved). It's just I wouldn't call _path_ the "obvious" word; I might opt for _walkway_.

Comment: J.R. that's probably due to personal preference or if someone is used to see seeing more paved or unpaved examples, in a particular part of the world.

Comment: True! It depends on context, too. For example, if I was told, "To get to work every day, I ride my bike on the path," I would assume it's a paved path, probably one similar to the O.P.'s picture. Incidentally, I had never thought much about the versatility of the word _path_ until contending with this question. There are footpaths, garden paths, metaphorical paths, paved paths, wooded paths, ski paths, covered paths, paths for golf carts and paths for bicycles – and dozens more. I doubt there's one word that can, by itself, invoke a picture exactly like the O.P.'s, not every time to everyone.